# CakePHP 2.1 Contact Form Data Won't Save

Tags: php, forms, email, cakephp

I have a few different contact forms in my CakePHP 2.0 application. All of the contact forms are emailing as they should, but I need this particular one to also save the form results to the database. The post data is populating, and I can `print_r()` and `pr()` the form data. I can even email the post data. However, it is not actually saving the data to the model table. The database table is named `contacts` and has the following fields: `id, publication, company, name, email, phone, message, contact_method, selections, received`.

Here is my model:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Contact';

    public $useTable = 'contacts';

    public $validate = array(  
    'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
```

Here is my controller:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class ContactsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Contacts';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js');
    public $components = array('Email', 'Session');

...

    public function contact_att() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            //pr($this->data);
            if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->redirect('/pages/publications-alabama-turf-times');
                $this->Session->setFlash("Mesage Saved!"); 
            }

            else {
                print_r($this->data);
                Configure::write('debug', 2); 
                debug($this->Contact->validationErrors); 

                exit;
            }
        }
```

Here is the form in my view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Contact', array(
    'action' => 'contact_att', 
    'label' => '', 
    'class' => 'pubs'));
echo $this->Form->input('publication', array(
    'type' => 'hidden', 
    'value' => 'A', 
    'label' => ''));
echo $this->Form->input('company', array(
    'default' => 'company name (required)', 
    'onfocus' => 'clearDefault(this)', 
        'label' => array(
            'text' => 'Company Name',
            'style' => 'position:absolute;')));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'default' => 'name (required)', 
    'onfocus' => 'clearDefault(this)', 
    'label' => array(
        'text' => 'Your Name',
        'style' => 'position:absolute;')));
echo $this->Form->input('phone', array(
    'default' => 'phone number (required)', 
    'onfocus' => 'clearDefault(this)', 
    'label' => array(
        'text' => 'Your Phone Number',
        'style' => 'position:absolute;')));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
    'default' => 'email (required)', 
    'onfocus' => 'clearDefault(this)', 
    'label' => array(
        'text' => 'Your Email Address',
        'style' => 'position:absolute;')));
echo $this->Form->input('message', array(
    'label' => array(
        'text' => 'Your Message',
        'style' => 'position:absolute;')));
echo $this->Form->input('contact_method', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'style' => 'padding-right:20px;', 
    'legend' => 'Preferred contact method:', 
    'options' => array(
        'phone' => 'phone',
        'email' => 'email'
        )
    ));
echo $this->Form->input('selections', array(
    'type' => 'select', 
    'label' => array(
    'text' => 'I am interested in the following:', 
    'style' => 'display:block; width:250px; margin-left:-12px;padding-bottom:15px;'),
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => array(
            'ABC' => 'ABC', 
            'DEF' => 'DEF', 
            'GHI' => 'GHI'
         )
    ));

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `debug($this->Contact->validationErrors);` output anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, no -- just an empty array. I have tried placing it before the save, in the if statement after the save, and in the else statement if the data did not save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much banging my head on the desk, the answer turned out to be simple -- of course. I simply removed this line from my model. I thought that having it set to the correct table would be fine, but turns out, it needed to be removed:

```
public $useTable = 'contacts';
```

Comment: Can you give us more info on what happened when you put that line? Was the query generated incorrectly? It might help someone else later. :)

Comment: Yes, when I removed that line, the query worked perfectly, except a problem with saving multiple checkbox selections. I solved that by compiling the array of data for that field into a string with a beforeSave() function in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$this->Contact->save($this->request->data, false);
```

Comment: How does that help? That just bypasses validation.

Comment: I was going to ask about the `false` parameter... that bypasses the validation? I tried removing the form validation, but that did not allow the form to save, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I did try this suggestion... still not saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
debug($this->model->invalidFields());
```

sometimes, model have errors on validations, and not shows with validationErrors()

also note this..

If $fieldList is not supplied, a malicious user can add additional fields to the form data (if you are not using SecurityComponent), and by this change fields that were not originally intended to be changed.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

take some time and read this documentation is very important, I hope have helped you.

Comment: I tried `debug($this->Contact->invalidFields());`, but it only output an empty array. I also updated `if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)` to `if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data, $fieldlist)`. Thanks for the tip regarding security, but right now, the problem is still that the data is not saving. I am fairly certain that the FormHelper is supposed to help prevent fields from being added. However, I tried it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, I see your problem, check..

This line is missing in your controller

```
public $uses = array('Contact');
```

put and try, then you told me...

Answer (score 0):

Is post will only return true when the form sets the posted hidden flag. So try this instead.

```
if(!empty($this->request->data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls add this line

```
$this->Contact->create();
```

before you tried to save using

```
if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
```